# What is the meaning of the XubuntuY string in Ubuntu package names?

Tags: package-management, packaging

Each package name is of the form:

```
package-XubuntuY*_amd64(i386)
```

So my questions are:

- What does the `X` stand for?
- What does the `Y` stand for?

For example, in `binutils_2.22-6ubuntu1.3_amd64`, what is the meaning of the numbers `6` and `1.3`?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/330018/what-is-the-standard-for-naming-deb-file-name

Comment: related http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/developers-reference/pkgs.html

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/604541/debian-packages-version-convention

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a detailed explanation [here](http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/17/ubuntu-package-version-naming-explanation/) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/604541/debian-packages-version-convention). If you are really interested you can read the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/) also.
To answer your questions:

- **X** is the Debian version of the package.
- **ubuntuY** is the Yth Ubuntu version of the Debian package.

To quote verbatim from the first link, `package-XubuntuY` means:

> 1. **package** = this is the name of the program/library.
> 2. **X** = this is the debian version of the package
>    ‐ if **X=0** this means that there is no debian package (or that the ubuntu team has forked a debian package to a newer version than the one found in the debian repositories)
>    *ex: bzip2-1.0.3-0ubuntu2*
>    (as shown in this example the debian package might be updated in the meantime and the ubuntu package will probably merged with it on the next version)
> 3. **ubuntuY** = this is the *Yth ubuntu* version of the debian package.
>    ‐ if this is *missing* this mean that it is a clean, unchanged debian package
>    *ex: gzip-1.3.5-12*
>    (in this sample, this is the original debian package included in ubuntu)
>    ‐ if this is *present* it means that Ubuntu has taken the debian package and released it with some additional patches or bug fixes.
>    *ex: sudo-1.6.8p12-1ubuntu6*
>    (in this sample this is the 6th version of the ubuntu package based on the debian version 1.6.8p12-1 of sudo).

Comment: Note: Ubuntu patches are stored under `debian/patches` on the deb, e.g. `apt-get source gdb`. You can also list all Ubuntu versions with changes between them with `bzr branch ubuntu:gdb; cd gdb; bzr log | less`

Comment: Is there a particular reason it's XubuntuY and not X+ubuntuY?