# How to tweak dpkg -l output

Tags: 14.04, dpkg

running `dpkg --list` gives me this output

```
ii  ucf                                           3.0036                      all                         Update Configuration File(s): preserve user changes to config files
ii  udev                                          229-4ubuntu11               amd64                       /dev/ and hotplug management daemon
ii  ufw                                           0.35-0ubuntu2               all                         program for managing a Netfilter firewall
ii  uidmap                                        1:4.2-3.1ubuntu5            amd64                       programs to help use subuids
ii  unattended-upgrades                           0.90                        all                         automatic installation of security upgrades
ii  unzip                                         6.0-20ubuntu1               amd64                       De-archiver for .zip files
```

Now for ex. let's take third row `ufw`

In third column where version numbers re written, I don't want it to return `0.35-0ubuntu2`. It should return only `0.35-0`
How can i do this?

Moreover what does this extra ubuntu11 denotes/means??

Comment: As for the "moreover": http://askubuntu.com/questions/620533/how-does-ubuntu-name-packages

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for `dpkg-query` with manual formatting for desired output, *on my system*:

```
% dpkg-query -Wf '${Version}\n' ufw  
0.34~rc-0ubuntu2
```

The `dpkg-query` specific variable `Version` expands to the version of the mentioned package, `ufw` in this case.

Now to get the portion before `ubuntu2`, you can set the width too after `Version`, separated by `;`:

```
% dpkg-query -Wf '${Version;9}\n' ufw
0.34~rc-0
```

but this is not reliable as the length can obviously vary for different possible versions; so you can leverage a bit of text-processing, here `grep`-ping (you can obviously use your tool of choice):

```
% dpkg-query -Wf '${Version}\n' ufw | grep -Po '.*?(?=ubuntu[^[:alpha:]]*$)'
0.34~rc-0
```

---

For the sake of completeness, if you insist on using `dpkg -l`, use a bit of `awk`:

```
%  dpkg -l | awk '$2=="ufw" {sub("ubuntu[^[:alpha:]]*$", "", $3); print $3}'
0.34~rc-0
```

Comment: this will not work in a case where version is `3.113+nmu3ubuntu3`

Comment: In my system this is the version of `adduser` package

Comment: to complete `ii  adduser                                       3.113+nmu3ubuntu3           all                         add and remove users and groups`

Comment: one more `1.26+nmu4ubuntu1` which is pretty similar to `adduser`

Comment: one more `4.1+Debian11ubuntu6` package name is `lsb-base`

Comment: @Constantine These are easy fix, check my edits.