# Is there some kind of category method for the packages used in the apt ecosystem?

Tags: apt, software-installation

As a rookie for Linux, I am wondering how should I understand the package name used in the `apt` ecosystem.

For example, here is some command to install sth.

```
apt-get install tk libglu1-mesa libtogl2 libfftw3-3 libxmu6 libgfortran4 \
      imagemagick openbabel
```

it seems some packages' names begin with `lib`, looks like a library, not sure if is dynamic or static, on the other hand, some packages' names look more like an execution file.
So is there some kind of standard used in the `apt` ecosystem, to make the name more obvious to users?

Comment: I don't think these two questions are related.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/330018/what-is-the-standard-for-naming-deb-file-name

Comment: Generally, Debian packagers (the source of most names) WANT folks to use the software, so they try to make the name somewhat useful, concise, and reasonably clear. It works -- you figured out the difference between libs and non-libs without any help!